# Phonegap - Change youtube embed link with value from database

Tags: javascript, mysql, html, cordova, youtube

im trying to implement a youtube embed video into my phonegap project. While the iframe works fine if you insert it into any page, im looking to load these videos from my mysql database. I want the video to appear within this structure:

```
        <div data-role="collapsible-set" id="gameVideo" data-theme="" data-content-theme="">
                                      <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
                                          <h3>
                                              Trailer
                                          </h3>
                                       <iframe width="300" height="169" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Jx3vb_AC0ZQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                                      </div>
```

All i need replacing is the iframe section to load the data from the database. Here is my javascript to load the data so far:

```
              function displayGame(data) {
game = data.item;
console.log(game);
$('#gamePic').attr('src', '' + game.Image);
$('#gameTitle').text(game.Title);
$('#gamePrice').text(game.Price);
$('#gameFormat').text(game.Format);
$('#gameStock').text(game.Stock);
$('#gameDesc').text(game.Description);
$('#gameVideo').attr('src', '' + game.Video);
$('#actionList').listview('refresh');
```

}

Any ideas?

Comment: So to be clear, you know that you can't run MySQL on the device, right? I assume you have a server setup with MySQL, and some form of application server in front of it (like ColdFusion, PHP, Ruby, etc) that can listen for requests and return the data.